# PHP's Mail Function Sending Many Duplicate Emails

Tags: php, email, sendmail

For some reason when I use PHP's mail function, a email can be sent two, three even more times. I am using PHP's mail function through the Zend Framework: framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.introduction.html

The same email is being sent with the same timestamp.

I believe this is due to this reason: kb.mediatemple.net/questions/774/Why+do+I+get+duplicate+emails%3F

Is there any solution for this?

BTW, i'm hosted on mediatemple's VPS which is running linux. I'm not sure whether this can be fixed through PHP or its a issue with the sendmail program.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out every call to *send* to find out if it's called multiple times, this way you know wheather the bug is in your PHP code or somewhere else.

Comment: Yep i've done that and the PHP code is not sending multiple times, that is the mail function is not being called multiple times.